# rails 3 has_many - use in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, has-many, many-to-one

I have a one-to-many relationship in my rails application:

- I have a User class that can have many Devices
- I have a Device class that belongs to a User

My Models are designed like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :devices
end

class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Regarding views, when I want to display all Users and list their associated Devices I use this code:

```
<%= user.devices.each do |device| %>
  <%= device.id %>
<% end %>
```

The output is: (only 1 device right now)

```
1 #<Device:0x101f45e50>
```

What I do not understand is why

```
#<Device:0x101f45e50>
```

is showing up after the id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace equal sign

```
<% user.devices.each do |device| %>
  <%= device.id %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It helped. So if you want to output something you use <%= and if you just want rails to do work use <%  . OK great thanks again

Answer (score 1):

To give a litte more context so you know why this occurred, the `=` parses the output AND displays the result from the statement in the resulting HTML, where the `-` parses the line but does NOT display the result — since ruby passes a result at every new statement, you must put your `=` and `-` in the right spots.

[Documentation is your friend (this is for HAML, but is still a good explanation)](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#inserting_ruby_)